# What time do/should/would I call you?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Here's the question I saw on a test:

A: What time ………… I call you?
B: You could call me after lunch.

a) am
b) do
c) should
d) would

I think *(b)*, *(c)*, and *(d)* are possible options. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I hope "should" be the best among your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking the other person to suggest a time convenient for him, "What time should I call you?" is the conventional way to ask. People do sometimes say, "What time do I call you?".

You should only use "What time would I call you?" if there is some question of whether you would call the person or not. The only times I can think of when I've heard this is when the question is asked hypothetically. Like, "All right, suppose I agree to your conditions and I decide that I will reply. What time would I call you?"

Answer (score 3):

All are possible, but (a) would be *What time am I to call you?* Each has a slightly different emphasis and the choice between them depends on the context and on the relationship between the two speakers.